# MVC4 Unable to call controller method using AJAX

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have following method in my controller:

```
public JsonResult GetRights(string ROLE_ID)
        {
            var result = db.APP_RIGHTS_TO_ROLES.Where(r => r.FK_ROLE_ID.ToString() == ROLE_ID).Select(r => r.APP_RIGHTS).ToList();
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

this is how I created a dropdownlist

```
@Html.DropDownList("ddlRoles", new SelectList(ViewBag.Roles, "ROLE_ID", "ROLE_NAME"),"--Select role--", new { onchange = "GetRights(this.value);" })
```

and finally a javascript snippet for dropdown item change

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function GetRights(role_id) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '@Url.Action("GetRights")',
                dataType: "json",
                data: { "ROLE_ID" : role_id.toString() }, 
                success: successFunc,
                error: errorFunc
            })
        }

        function successFunc (data) {
            alert("success");
            if (data != null) {
                var vData = data;
            }
        }

        function errorFunc() {
            alert("error");
        };
    </script>
```

I can see that javascript function is being called while changing selected item but I am not being navigated to method in my controller. Can somebody help me whats wrong in there?
Thanks

Comment: Open Network tab of Developer tools and find this XHR request. What is the status of it? Any errors?

Comment: Try checking actual Url in Browsers developer tool when you change selected item.

Comment: Thanks for response. I am getting error HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Comment: its a normal controller

Comment: What is the controller name? Because if it is not the default controller I would expect `Url.Action("GetRights", "ControllerName")`

Comment: Can you post your routes from the route.config file. May be you need to create a route for it

Comment: I do not have route.config file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out that now. It was totally stupid me. I did commented out the following:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

But I was not be able to see that :(. Included jquery now and everything seems to be correct.
Thanks to everybody for their help

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way you should perform GET request with AJAX. In GET, parameters have to be passed in url string, so your url parameter in AJAX should look like:

```
http://someaddress/GetRights?ROLE_ID=sometexthere
```

You can check in browser console/debugger where do you fire your reqest to. Also you can manually fire the same request from browser, as this is normal GET.

Comment: _This is not the way you should perform GET request with AJAX_
Can you  back up that claim?

Comment: I am able to fire request manually which gave me expected results, however still not be able to do that using AJAX. I also tried complete hard coded url but no success